# Unable to open file "lb.sql" when using Terraform resource "null_resource" "sqlcl-liquibase"

Tags: terraform, devops, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, hashicorp, terraform-provider-oci

I'm using OCI DevOps and terraform to create DB and run liquibase changelog against it.
After the DB created and wallet and connected to DB successfully I'm receiving this Error:
unable to open file "lb.sql"
My Terraform script is:

```
resource "null_resource" "sqlcl-liquibase" {

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command     = <<-EOT
    ./sqlcl/bin/sql -cloudconfig wallet.zip admin/${random_string.password.result}@sandboxProd_high @lb.sql
    EOT
    working_dir = path.module
  }

  depends_on = [
    local_file.autonomous_database_wallet_file,
  ]
}
```

Comment: Where does `lb.sql` file exist? Does it exist in `path.module` directory?

Comment: Hi @harshavmb, it exist in path.module in my root repository.